# Problem with Google Webmaster Tools Sitemap

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, xml-sitemap, multi-subdomains

I have a WPMU 3.6.1 with Domain Mapping (0.5.4.3) with W3TC (0.9.3) and Google XML Sitemaps (4.0 BETA).

I have 4 different sitemaps.

- *sub-1.com/sitemap.xml*
- *sub-2.com/sitemap.xml*
- *sub-3.com/sitemap.xml*
- *sub-4.com/sitemap.xml*

on Google Webmaster Tools, I got 59 errors and 14 warnings.

#### Sitemap errors > Errors:

> We encountered an error while trying to access your Sitemap. Please
> ensure your Sitemap follows our guidelines and can be accessed at the
> location you provided and then resubmit.
>
> General HTTP error: 404 not found
>
> Sitemap: *sub-2.com/sitemap-pt-post-2011-02.xml*

etc.

But when I click on my sitemap links they work fine.

#### Sitemap errors > Warnings:

> URLs not accessible When we tested a sample of the URLs from your
> Sitemap, we found that some URLs were not accessible to Googlebot due
> to an HTTP status error. All accessible URLs will still be submitted.
>
> Sitemap: *sub-2.com/sitemap-misc.xml*
>
> HTTP Error: 404
>
> URL: `/sitemap.html`

But when I click on my sitemap links they work fine.

#### Sitemap errors > Index errors:

> URLs not accessible When we tested a sample of the URLs from your
> Sitemap, we found that some URLs were not accessible to Googlebot due
> to an HTTP status error. All accessible URLs will still be submitted.
>
> HTTP Error: 404
>
> URL: */sitemap-pt-post-2010-09.xml*

But when I click on my sitemap links they work fine.

#### Web pages

- 3,276 Submitted
- 3,247 Indexed

What do I have to put on ***network admin > performance(w3tc) > page cache > cache preload > Sitemap URL*** ?

I have added **"*/sitemap.xml*"**

My *robots.txt*: http://pastebin.com/3K2U0mQa

My *.htaccess*:  http://pastebin.com/efJJ6zwy

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two suggestions:

1. Check your server logs.  Make sure that everybody that is able to access these files gets the expected status.  See if these pages returned 404 errors to Googlebot.
2. Use the "Fetch as Google" feature in webmaster tools in the "Crawl" menu to try to access these resources.

Your problem is likely to be one of the following:

- You have invalid links in your sitemap (but you say everything works when you click on them)
- Your site is not up all the time and sometimes Google crawls it when it is serving 404 pages
- Your site has some sort of rule that prevents Googlebot from crawling certain pages and serves 404 errors to it by user agent or IP address.

Comment: my robots.txt: http://pastebin.com/3K2U0mQa
my .htaccess:  http://pastebin.com/efJJ6zwy

Comment: also i can't find the "download as Googlebot"

Comment: Its now called "Fetch as Google", I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I fixed it, the problem comes from some rules. thnx for your help :)